# Chrome extension function not returning value to caller function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extention that is communicating with the background tab to get a certain `sid`, then I am trying to create some buttons with the `sid`. Here is the function that calls the background tab:

```
function call_background_tab(req) {
    switch (req) {
        case "zbx_sessionid":
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({item: req}, function(response) {
                var rsp = response["response"][0]["value"];
                console.log("call_background_tab: " + rsp); // <- this works
                return rsp;
            });
    }
}
```

I am calling the function in the following code:

```
let sid = call_background_tab("zbx_sessionid");
console.log("main: " + sid); // <- this does not work, returns undefined
add_CheckNow_Button(sid);
```

After refreshing the page, in the console, I see:

```
main: undefined
call_background_tab: bfe92fcafbc7d4e09fccc8de595dcc21
```

I have tried putting the `console.log("main: " + sid)` and `add_CheckNow_Button(sid);` lines inside a `setTimeout()` block, where the `main` output gets printed after the `call_background_tab` output, but I still see the `main` one as undefined, while `call_background_tab` returns a valid session id.

Why am I unable to get the value of `rsp` to the caller? Thanks.

Comment: From the title *Chrome extension function gets data from background but*...But, what?.   BTW, when you're trying to assign the return value of ```call_background_tab("zbx_sessionid")``` to ```sid```, the ```sendMessage``` method hasn't finished executing and hasn't returned a value, so the ```sid``` is ```undefined```. You can fix it then using ```Promises``` or ```async/await```.

Comment: Hi @KeyboardCorporation, I apologize, I fixed the title now. I will try your suggestions and let you know where it goes. Thanks!